# Action function not callable - using Typescript, react-redux and redux-starter-kit

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

Getting a Typescript error "This expression is not callable" when creating an action using the createSlice() method. Shouldn't `toggleDarkTheme()` return the action that can be used when dispatching?

```
 import { createSlice, Slice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { AppState } from "../types";

const initialState: AppState = {
  darkTheme: false
};

const appStateSlice: Slice<AppState> = createSlice({
  name: "appState",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleDarkTheme: (state: AppState) => ({
      ...state,
      darkTheme: !state.darkTheme
    })
  }
});

export const { toggleDarkTheme } = appStateSlice.actions;
console.log(toggleDarkTheme()); //ERROR "expression is not callable"

export default appStateSlice.reducer;
```

Here is the full TS error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'void | WithTypeProperty<WithMatch<() => WithPayload<undefined, Action<string>>, string, undefined, never, never>, string> | WithTypeProperty<WithMatch<{ (payload?: undefined): WithPayload<undefined, Action<...>>; <PT extends unknown>(payload?: PT | undefined): WithPayload<...>; }, string, unknown, never, never>, str...' are callable.
    Type 'void' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. I had a few things wrong but the biggest issue I think was trying to type it with Slice. I'm pretty new with Typescript so if anyone understands how to properly type this, I would love to see how.

```
  import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { AppState } from "types";

const initialState: AppState = {
  darkTheme: false
};

const appStateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "appState",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleDarkTheme(state: AppState) {
      state.darkTheme = !state.darkTheme;
    }
  }
});

export const { toggleDarkTheme } = appStateSlice.actions;
console.log(toggleDarkTheme());

export default appStateSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Yes, you don't need to declare any generic types for `createSlice` itself.  It infers the type of the slice's state from the `initialState` parameter.  The [Redux Toolkit "Advanced Tutorial" docs page shows how to define types for reducers and other usage](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial).  Side question: out of curiosity, where did you first hear about RTK?

Comment: I have been following the development of: https://github.com/taniarascia/takenote and learning lots of new tricks. RTK was something the team implemented a little while ago and I thought I would try it out in one of my projects.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah, [I suggested early on that TakeNote should use Redux Toolkit](https://github.com/taniarascia/takenote/issues/4) - glad to see that it _is_ being used, and that it's proving useful!